# Impossible to redirect output of docker-compose v2 on macOS

Tags: docker, docker-compose, terminal, io-redirection, pty

When running:

```sh
docker-compose up -d
docker-compose exec test echo hello > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

where `docker-compose.yml` is:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  test:
    image: ubuntu
    command: tail -f /dev/null
```

the terminal still displays:

```
hello
```

while I would expect it to display nothing (since both stdout and stderr are redirected to /dev/null).

How can a program display anything on the terminal without going through stdout/stderr?

EDIT: There seems to be an issue opened on docker-compose: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/9104

### Investigation

The issue is not present with docker-compose v1:

```
docker-compose-v1 exec test echo hello > /dev/null
```

outputs nothing.

The issue is not present when forcing not to use a pseudo-tty:

```
docker-compose exec -T test echo hello > /dev/null
```

outputs nothing.

The issue is not present when using `docker` directly:

```
docker run ubuntu echo hello > /dev/null
```

outputs nothing.

Even when forcing the use of a pseudotty:

```
docker run -it ubuntu echo hello > /dev/null
```

### OS and Docker version

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.22
 Version:           20.10.12
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.12
 Git commit:        e91ed57
 Built:             Mon Dec 13 11:46:56 2021
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.12
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.16.12
  Git commit:       459d0df
  Built:            Mon Dec 13 11:43:56 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.12
  GitCommit:        7b11cfaabd73bb80907dd23182b9347b4245eb5d
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.2
  GitCommit:        v1.0.2-0-g52b36a2
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0

$ docker-compose version
Docker Compose version v2.2.3
```

OS = macOS 11.6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this has been fixed. I have just tested it with docker-compose version 2.6.1 and it doesn't show any output.

```
❯ docker-compose up --build --force-recreate -d
[+] Running 2/2
 ⠿ Network docker-test_default   Created                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.1s
 ⠿ Container docker-test-test-1  Started                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.5s
❯ docker-compose exec test echo hello > /dev/null 2> /dev/null

❯ docker version
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.24
 Version:           20.10.17
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.17.11
 Git commit:        100c701
 Built:             Mon Jun  6 23:04:45 2022
 OS/Arch:           darwin/arm64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Desktop 4.10.1 (82475)
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.17
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.17.11
  Git commit:       a89b842
  Built:            Mon Jun  6 23:01:01 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/arm64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.6
  GitCommit:        10c12954828e7c7c9b6e0ea9b0c02b01407d3ae1
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.2
  GitCommit:        v1.1.2-0-ga916309
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0

❯ docker-compose version
Docker Compose version v2.6.1
❯
```

MacOs = 12.3.1 ; M1 processor

As a side note, [Docker-compose v2 has been made Generally Available on late April 2022](https://www.docker.com/blog/announcing-compose-v2-general-availability/)